# How do I succesfully host a asp.net mvc app on shared hosting without resorting to ugly URLs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting

Let's assume we're talking about the recently released Beta version.  Specifically I'm interested in a step-by-step tutorial or similar, and I'd be thrilled with information addressing how to do so on CrystalTech.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I was looking for a hosting provider for a while and finally stumbled upon http://www.softsyshosting.com/ and bought an account. I've been so busy in work stuff lately I didn't even think about the wild card issue. Hope the w2k8 helps with this. I'll let you know.

Comment: Haven't figured it out.  Leave a comment here if you get something working.  I get the feeling we won't be waiting too long till MVC is released.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you want a hosting environment that uses Windows Server 2008 / IIS7, which allows you configure things like mappings through the web.config rather than through IIS itself.

Failing that, your only choice is to either ask CrystalTech to enable ASP.NET wildcard mapping to your website or just stick with using .mvc extensions in your URLs.